# How to align the label using CSS so that it looks same in all browsers

Tags: html, css

How to align labels in same way because if am using `style=textalign:end` it shift the label before textbox and looks fine in Google chrome but in IE10 label position change to start.

Can anyone please tell me is there any common css that works in all browsers and gives same look and feel.

```
<td style="text-align: end">
  <asp:Label ID="lblParameterA" runat="server" Text="a" CssClass="lblNormal"></asp:Label>
</td>

<td>
  <asp:TextBox ID="textbox1" runat="server" Width="90px" CssClass="txtMediumText">  </asp:TextBox>
  <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" CssClass="mandatory" ControlToValidate="textbox1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
  <span class="mandatory">*</span>
</td>
```

Comment: `text-align` with `end` or `start` does not work in any current version of IE. You should still use `left` and `right` unfortunately, if you want IE to play along.

Answer (score 3):

From MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align
"This is an experimental API that should not be used in production code."

[image]
[image]

You won't be able to make it cross-browser.
It's still on the [working draft of css level-3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/#text-align), per october 2013

Comment: Thanks Milche ,so what to do I checked the link that you suggest can you please tell me the exact solution what to do to solve my problem?

Comment: User setek and me allready did help you, you won't be able to achive what you want with text-align:end .. so change you design.